# Problems with initializing CamShift algorithm

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing, mean-shift

I use matlab to implement a tracker using cam shift. I need to implement it myself hence I'm not using the built in method.

I let the user choose the object to track and after the first iteration the convergence makes it start tracking a different object. pictures speaks louder than words so:

I choose my face in the first frame:
[image: What I choose]

It converges to my shoulder and starting tracking it:
[image: After first iteration]

Now the tracking is overall ok throughout the video so I think the issue is in the initialization phase.

SomeCode: Get position from user:

```
function [pos] = getObjectPosition(F)
f = figure;
imshow(F);
pos = getPosition(imrect(gca));
close(f);
end
```

Main Loop:

```
firstFrame = readFrame(input);
pos = getObjectPosition(firstFrame);

while hasFrame(input)
% init next frame
nextFrame = readFrame(input);
[currFrameHSV, ~, ~] = rgb2hsv(nextFrame);
frameHue = double(currFrameHSV(:,:,1));

% init while loop vars 
prevX = -1;
prevY = -1;
i = 0;
while (i < numOfIterations) && ~(prevX == pos(1) && prevY == pos(2))
    % updating the curr iteration number
    i = i + 1;
    % getting search window location and dimensions
    envRect = round(getEnvRect(pos,pos(4)/yRatio,pos(3)/xRatio,height,width));

    [X,Y] = meshgrid(envRect(1):envRect(1) + envRect(3),...
                     envRect(2):envRect(2) + envRect(4));

    % getting the sub image
    I = imcrop(frameHue,envRect);

    M00 = sum(sum(I));
    M10 = sum(sum(X.*I));
    M01 = sum(sum(Y.*I));

    % getting center mass location
    Xc = round(M10/M00);
    Yc = round(M01/M00);

    % updating object position
    prevX = pos(1);
    prevY = pos(2);
    pos(1) = floor(Xc - pos(3)/2);
    pos(2) = floor(Yc - pos(4)/2);

end

% adding the object's bounding box to the frame to write
% show the image
end
```

getEnv method:

```
function [ envRect ] = getEnvRect( feature,hShift,wShift,rows,cols )
hEnvSize = feature(4) + 2*hShift; 
wEnvSize = feature(3) + 2*wShift;
xPatch  = feature(1);
xEnv    = max(1, xPatch - wShift);
yPatch  = feature(2);
yEnv    = max(1, yPatch - hShift);
width   = min(cols, xEnv + wEnvSize) - xEnv;
height  = min(rows, yEnv + hEnvSize) - yEnv;

envRect = [xEnv, yEnv, width, height];
end
```

Comment: Does the next frame tracker always move down?

Comment: When choosing the same rectangle yes, but for other objects no

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. If you put it on your face it moves to your shoulders but if you put it on your, say, waist, it stays there?

Comment: It will move to down right or upper left or even worse to a piece of wall which doesn't move and the tracking wont work

Comment: You are not passing the user-chosen rectangle to any loop.

Comment: Pos is the first parameter when I calculate center mass, at first it holds the user selected coordinates